# Empty Integer Field in Django Model returns error in GraphQL

Tags: django-models, graphql

In one of my Django models I have this field:

```html
version = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

To test it, I manually created a new record via the DBBrowser for SQLite and left the field blank.

When I then issued a GraphQL query on the object, I received this error message back:

```
"errors": [ { "message": "could not convert string to float: " } ]
```

Updating the empty field to 0 or 1 or 2, etc., the error message disappeared.

I don't consider an empty field to be an error, especially because I specifically stated in the field definition that it could be empty.  Short of having a default value of 0 (zero), how do I fix this to get rid of the error message?

Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlite has stored an empty string, instead of `NULL`, in your `version` column, which `graphene.Int` can't handle. Normally django won't let this happen when you save through it. If you want to worry about values created externally then you can add a resolver to your model to make sure `None` is returned instead of an empty string.

```
class MyModel(DjangoObjectType):

    @graphene.resolve_only_args
    def resolve_version(self):
        return self.version or None
```

Comment: I believe you, of course.  What's odd to me is how a string could possibly get stored into an integer field.  How is that possible?

As it turns out, I had to delete my test database and let Django recreate it from scratch.  Voila, the error is no longer appearing.  Now `null` appears in the version field when I create a new record and don't specify a `version` value.

Comment: @Robert_LY Sqlite allows that to happen, so you can do it through an sqlite editor or something like that, but not through django. You can read more [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106364/text-string-stored-in-sqlite-integer-column).

Comment: I didn't realize that.  Then definitely likely the result of manual editing I was doing.  Thanks!